# Not able to make the polar charts fill the entire quadrant in Anychart

Tags: javascript, jquery, radar-chart, anychart

I am creating a polar chart using [AnyChart](https://www.anychart.com/)

[image]

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    // create polar chart
    var chart = anychart.polar();

    var columnSeries = chart.column([
        {x: 'A', value: 28.7},
        {x: 'B', value: 19},
        {x: 'C', value: 17.7},       
        {x: 'D', value: 34.7}
    ]);

    // set series name
    columnSeries.name('Percentage');

    // set title settings
    chart.title()
            .enabled(true)
            .text('Test')
            .padding({bottom: 20});

    // disable y-axis
    chart.yAxis(false);

    // set value prefix for tooltip
    chart.tooltip().valuePrefix('%');

    // set x-scale
    chart.xScale('ordinal');

    // set chart container id
    chart.container('container');

    // initiate chart drawing
    chart.draw();
});
```

https://playground.anychart.com/gallery/Polar_Charts/Column_Polar_Chart

I would like to get graphs fill up the entire quadrant similar to:

[image]

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [sort the points](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.charts.Polar#sortPointsByX) according to your column

```
// enable sorting points by x
chart.sortPointsByX(true);
```

Check the [live example](https://playground.anychart.com/docs/8.2.1/samples/BCT_Polar_Column_Chart)

Answer (score 0):

Setting `chart.sortPointsByX(true);` fixed the issue:

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    // create polar chart
    var chart = anychart.polar();

    var columnSeries = chart.column([
        {x: 'A', value: 28.7},
        {x: 'B', value: 19},
        {x: 'C', value: 17.7},       
        {x: 'D', value: 34.7}
    ]);

    // set series name
    columnSeries.name('Percentage');

    // set title settings
    chart.title()
            .enabled(true)
            .text('Test')
            .padding({bottom: 20});

    // disable y-axis
    chart.yAxis(false);

    // set value prefix for tooltip
    chart.tooltip().valuePrefix('%');

    chart.sortPointsByX(true);

    // set x-scale
    chart.xScale('ordinal');

    // set chart container id
    chart.container('container');

    // initiate chart drawing
    chart.draw();
});
```

[image]